# Outputting different levels in a nested list

Tags: scheme, racket

Quick question trying to figure this out before an exam I have.

If I have a nested list such as

```
(list 1 (list 2 3 ( list 4 (list 6))))
```

How would I write a function that would give me the lowest level only or the 3rd level?

For example the lowest level would output `'(6)` and the 3rd would output `'(4)`.

I was debating maybe using a flattem but then I wouldn't know the levels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add some code to show that you have tried and to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive descent and pass the current level as an extra argument.

```
(define (collect s-exp level) ...)

 1. If s-exp is empty return '()
 2. If s-exp is a pair, (cons a d), then
    2a. if a is a pair, then recurse on a with an increased level
    2b. if level is below 3
          3a recurse on a
          3b recurse on d
          3c. append the results from 3a and 3b
    2c  if level is 3
          4a recurse on d
          4b append (list a) with the result from 4a
```